# Resonant Frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, frequency

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSHsna.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, for series circuit to find resonance we have to have values of impedances (L and C) to be equal.
And then resonant frequency can be calculated wl and 1/wc but this is combination of elements how to find resonant frequency here. Is there any formula for this?
Zeq={(1*-jXc)/1-jXc} + jXl

Comment: Do you mean maximum impedance or, impedance where the value is purely resistive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, notice that the input impedance of your circuit is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\left(\omega\right)&=\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}+\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{C}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\text{L}\omega\text{j}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\text{L}\omega\text{j}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1-\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle1-\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\text{L}\omega\text{j}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(1-\text{CR}\omega\text{j}\right)}{\displaystyle1^2+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{L}\omega\text{j}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}-\text{CR}^2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{L}\omega\text{j}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2\omega}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\cdot\text{j}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}+\left(\text{L}\omega-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2\omega}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)\text{j}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}+\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)\text{j}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we can see that the amplitude of the input impedance is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\left(\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}+\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)\text{j}\right|\\
\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}\right)\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

Solving:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\left(\omega\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\partial\omega}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_0=\dots\tag3$$

Gives:

$$\omega_0=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{C}^2\text{R}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\sqrt{\text{C}^5\left(2\text{L}+\text{CR}^2\right)}-\text{C}^2}\tag4$$

Using your values, we find:

$$\omega_0=\sqrt{2\sqrt{30}-1}\approx3.15507\space\text{rad/sec}\tag5$$

And:

$$\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\left(\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{\sqrt{4\sqrt{30}-21}}{10}\approx0.0953364\space\Omega\tag6$$

Comment: Excellent derivation! A small adjustment: in (4) may be clearer to keep omega as 1/(RC) times radical, and it seems the C can be taken inside (as C^2, and then C^4 inside the second radical) to useful effect. Some discussion might also be illuminating: why this change (what units are omega and 1/(RC)?); for which R/Z_o do we get omega^2 ~= 1/(LC), or omega ~= 1/(RC); and removing the "~" from these, expressing it as omega_0 +/- omega_d (damped or difference).

Comment: Understood its complex though. After finding equivalent impedance,  Z=R1+(CRω)2 + ω(L−CR21+(CRω)2)j(1) i did separate real and imaginary parts, my Prof just said that equate that imaginary part to 0. So, ω(L−CR21+(CRω)=0 which gives ω=3 rad/sec which is given answer. But why? Why do we equate imaginary part to 0.